# Term for a movie that tells a lot through its backdrop?

Tags: analysis, terminology

I'm writing a paper about a movie that exerts a lot of social and cultural criticism through its backdrop - things like posters, graffiti, murals and so on. They are not central to the story at all (it's a love story), but they kind of tell a story in themselves and become very relevant when interpreting the film.

Is there a term for this kind of film?

Comment: Well, the name of the film might help.

Comment: I can do that if you feel it adds to the question, but I'm really looking for the term in general terms (and it is likely to be a very esoteric one, as this is hardly a dominating feature). It's *Monsters:* http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1470827/

Comment: Perhaps if you could post some screen shots of the specific art design choices you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be a type of script Symbology forming a movie motif in the background. This would most likely place it in the catorgory of film making under the heading symbols =  "an object in a film that stands for an idea, or that has a second level of meaning to it, e.g., a window or train=freedom, a rose=beauty, a cross-roads=a decision point, etc.; the more a symbol is repeated, the greater its significance" as per [Film Terms Glossary](http://www.filmsite.org/filmterms19.html)